# Unclosed Parenthesis exception on CREATE in spring-data-neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm running Spring Data Neo4j version 2.3.3. When I try to execute a CREATE statement through my `GraphRepository`, I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement ...  nested exception is Unclosed parenthesis
"CREATE (:line{id:1})-[:ROOT]->(:point{id:10})-[:NEXT]->(:point{id:11})-[:NEXT]->(:point{id:12})-[:NEXT]->(p:point{id:13})"
         ^
```

The `...` merely hides the same thing printed below it, and the `^` appears in the correct place. As you can see if you look at my query, there is no unclosed parenthesis. What's going on here?

***EDIT:*** For testing purposes, I tried reducing the statement to: `CREATE (:line{id:1})`, and I get the same result.

***EDIT:*** I tried upgrading my pom to use version 3.0.0, and now am getting the following exception:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.example.model.LineRepo org.example.controller.Controller.lineRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lineRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@61634a3b' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
```

The deepest root cause exception given is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileSystemAbstraction.getOrCreateThirdPartyFileSystem(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/neo4j/helpers/Function;)Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/nioneo/store/FileSystemAbstraction$ThirdPartyFileSystem;
```

Nothing was changed other than upgrading the dependency. The `'controller'` bean it is referring to is the controller I have `@Autowired` with my `GraphRepository`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j 2.3.3 is for Neo4j 1.9, which doesn't support labels (the syntax you're using in Cypher). You need to use 3.0.0 in order to get Neo4j 2.0 support.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried upgrading my pom to use 3.0.0, and am now getting a different exception. Please see my edit.

Comment: if you're starting this on the same store, you'll need to set the options to allow upgrade.